# JSON to Object conversion in Java

Tags: java, json

Lets take a example my object Person having 2 properties below

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    Integer age;

    //getters and setters
}
```

but jsonaray contains more than 2 properties

```
[{
    "name": "ab",
    "age": 18,
    "c": "dc",
    "d": "ef"
}]
```

Here extra elements c and d are there. Can I convert that jsonarray to set person object?

Comment: Which json library are you using?

Comment: Also, what do you want to happen to the extra elements c and d?

Comment: Do you want to iignore c and d?

Comment: Btw, your JSON is invalid. There should be no "," after "d":"ef"

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Nishit, Thanks i updated my json and yes i want to ignore c and d

Comment: @Joni i want to ignore those elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't know which library you are using, I would go ahead and assume you are using the most common one - **Jackson**.

Use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation on your `Person` class.
This annotation allows you to ignore any field in the JSON which doesn't map to the fields in your POJO.

Answer (score 1):

You have got multiple options

1. Code a JSON Parse your self(Which I hope is not the expectation here).
2. Use frameworks/JSON parser libraries available.

One such framework is [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson). You can achieve what you need as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   //Step 1. Create and set properties of ObjectMapper.
   // You need FAIL for unknow properties false for your case
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
       
   String jsonStr = {
                    "name": "ab",
                    "age": 18,
                    "c": "dc",
                    "d": "ef"
                   };
       try{
            //Step 2: call mapper to convert it to your class
            Person person = mapper.convertValue(jsonStr, Data.class);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
            //log error
        }
}
```